# Why is Office Interop reference showing erroring in VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I created a solution using the previous VS now I have opened this Solution in VS 2010 and this reference seems to be incorrect:

[image]

It was fine before and the program has been running ok everyday for a couple of months; so why is the VS 2010 telling me this?

In the Solution Explorer it looks like something is wrong with the reference. Was fine before:

[image]

Ok - I've just deleted the reference above then found this build (**which looks exactly the same**) and added it and all seems good in the World now!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently installed the new `VS` therefore I believe it also installed the newest version of the `.NET framework`. So I suspect when I opened this project it was pointed at a more recent framework version which has caused a problem with the reference.

I deleted the broken reference and added it back in and it seems fine now.

Answer (score 2):

Have you referenced the office dll as well as just adding a using statement. Or if it has been running fine is the DLL missing or the reference been removed.  Mostly likely cause is that the DLL was in the GAC of the machine it was developed on and it is not on the current one.

Comment: seems like it still runs ok .....I just built the solution; then ran the 'exe' in the 'bin' directory and it runs through ok. But if I try to step into the program in VS it errors.

Comment: Do a clean and rebuild, it's got an old DLL hanging round somewhere that allows it to build.

Comment: see my edit ....think I've effectively done what you suggested; seems like I've deleted a reference to a DLL and then added a reference to the same DLL !!

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because the current version of VS hasn't the right dll loaded. So if I were you I would have look on how you can enable some of the references you need. I don't know how you can enable them, or which you have to enable. But I know I've had this problem before and it solved my problem.
Just Google the error and you will probably find the solution for it.

Comment: my machine has 'Office' installed - which includes `Excel` - so seems a bit strange